# How to change the Title of the command prompt window

Tags: c, winapi

How can I change the title of the command prompt window every time I execute a dos-based program by double clicking it, in c language. Should I use the Windows API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SetConsoleTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686050.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`title` allows to set this:

```
title Windows Title (quotes unneeded)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

%comspec% /c start "testtest" %comspec%

at application launcher of Windows+R